# Add MovieClips from Stage to an Array and play them

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, compiler-errors, movieclip

I have added specific MovieClips from my stage to an array using;

```
var ItemArray:Array = new Array();


function loadItems():Array //loads/returns items into an array
{

    for(var i:int = 0; i<numChildren; i++) //loop number of children on stage
    {

        if(getChildAt(i).name.substr(0,4) == "item") //if child is an item

            {
            ItemArray[getChildAt(i).name.substr(5)] = getChildAt(i); //Add to Items:array as instance numbered
            }
    }

return ItemArray;    
}
```

Then when I hit a button it fires this function:

```
function playNextItem():void
{
        if(CurrentItem < ItemArray.length)
    {
        play.ItemArray[CurrentItem];
        CurrentItem++;
    }

}
```

Which plays the first moviclip of the array and adds +1 to a counter so the next time I hit the button it plays the next Movieclip in the array.

But I get this error:

```
/Users/nathanrichman/Desktop/Presso Idea/Presentation.as, Line 50, Column 7 1119: Access of possibly undefined property ItemArray through a reference with static type Function.
```

I've looked around and it seems like i'm creating the array all wrong and it can't read it as a Movieclip.

How do I add movieclips to an array and play.array[number]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one hand, [play()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#play%28%29) is a movieClip `method`, not the opposite!

The correct code isn't:

```
play.mc;
```

but:

```
mc.play();
```

On the other hand, you can do it simply like that:

```
var ItemArray:Array = [];

for (var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
{
    ItemArray[i] = MovieClip(getChildAt(i));
}

var CurrentItem:int = 0;

function playNextItem(e:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    ItemArray[CurrentItem].play();
    CurrentItem++;
}
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, playNextItem);
```